# Why is Membership and Role Manager and Profile initially in Machine.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Why is Membership and Role Manager and Profile generated initially in Machine.config when the ASPNETDB is first created?

It's been a pain to reconfigure my application to work,  I had to move code from Machine.config to Web.config to get my Application services working again for preparing to release to my ISP webspace.

Regards
Tea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to touch Machine.config. Most of the hosting service won't even let you change their Machine.config.

You can use either `<clear/>` or `<remove name="DefaultMembershipProvider" />` in your application's web.config.

[Common Gotcha: Don't forget to  when adding providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/20/common-gotcha-don-t-forget-to-clear-when-adding-providers.aspx)

**Updated 12/20/2012**

By default, if you create a new project in Visual Studio 2012, membership tags are created automatically.

Or you can even use NutGet

[image]

Comment: I meant the machine.config on my laptop that currently holds my web application.  I had to go into that and copy to web.config.

Comment: Sound like you are using old ASP.Net Membership Provider. If so, please use new Universal Membership Provider. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

Comment: I didn't know the code I needed, so I went into Machine.config, copied and pasted it in web.config, added clear and connectionstrings.

Comment: You can use NuGet to get ASP.Net Universal Providers. I updated the answer.

Comment: Would most decent ISP's web servers hosting 4.0 be upgraded automatically to work it it?

Comment: It is nothing to do with web server. You just need to make sure it is included in your project's bin folder when you publish.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, it's always been in machine.config.  You just didn't notice it before because Visual Studio would automatically generate a new provider entry in your web.config for you.  As part of a move to reduce the size of the web.configs, Microsoft no longer generates many entries, including this one, allowing you to add your own if you want one.

Comment: Yeah, machine.config is well based on your laptop.  Web.config, it usually is copied to your ISP web space.  Not sure having it in machine.config is a step backwards.